# How to have an ADODB.Connection use IBM i login information?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, ibm-midrange

I can create an ADOBC.Connection and query the IBM i database when I supply the UID and PWD.  But I'd rather not supply the password in the VBA code.
I thought that there should be a way to use my current sign on information or if no previous sign on have the IBM i prompt for user and password.

In my VBA CODE If I use the connection string

```
ConString = "Driver={IBM I Access ODBC Driver};    " & _
            "SYSTEM=" & DBSystem & "; " & _
            "DATABASE=" & DBDatabase & "; " & _
            "UID=" & DBuid & "; " & _
            "PWD=" & DBpwd & "; "
```

and set the UID and PWD variables to my sign on credentials then I can query the database.
I have installed the latest ODBC driver from IBM (IBM i Access ODBC Driver) and configured a user data source.
On the General Tab for the DSN setup if I press the Connection Options button the a radio button for Use IBM i Navigator default which I have selected.

I thought that be selecting this radio button then my credentials from an existing session would be used or an IBM i prompt would be displayed much the same as when I start a new Run SQL Scripts or 5250 session.

Answer (score 1):

That prompt is part of the 5250 terminal program, not the driver. If you want a password prompt, just code one. Not sure how to use current session's password (though obviously it is possible).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  You make the comment (obviously it's possible).  You get the same prompt window/box if you start Run Sql Scripts before starting a session.  If you already have a session started you don't need to supply your credentials. Is this why you say it's possible?

Comment: I know it is possible because iACS gives you the option to use your Windows credentials. In this case your IBM i user id and password have to be the same as your Windows user id and password, but it does work. Therefore, there is a way to make that happen, not sure how to do it though.

Comment: I've been unable to find how to do this as well.  But I added a prompt in VBA for the user and password as a workaround. Thanks again Mark.